# Java POI/docx4j generate Word file with several repeating entries

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I have an example `.docx` template with text plus placeholder keys as shown below:

```
I ${Full_Name_n} accept terms and condition stated in ${Signed_Doc_n} and is liable for ...
```

Is there an elegant approach from docx4j camp that can generate 1 .docx for **n** number of individuals using the above text block ?

I have a POI class that does this my merging n number of .docx into 1 which is very dirty and not acceptable performance-wise.

P.S. Template text will have paragraphs and paragraphs suspended into tables. Images will not be involved.

**For example here is my template saved in 1 word file:**

```
I ${Full_Name_n} accept terms and condition stated in ${Signed_Doc_n} ...
```

**And this is what I expect to be the output, that is several entries in 1 word file:**

```
I Bill smth accept terms and condition stated in article 10 ...

I John smth accept terms and condition stated in article 21 ...

I Sterling smth accept terms and condition stated in article 11 ...

I Joshua smth accept terms and condition stated in article 13 ...
```

Comment: Do you want to create N copies of your input docx (in a single output docx), or 1 copy of your input docx (with repeating portions eg rows of a table, list items, or whatever)?  Both are possible with docx4j.

Comment: N copies of my input docx in a single output docx I presume

Comment: Hidden extending table will not do because the INPUT may be comprised of  both TEXT and hidden/visible TABLEs

Comment: You could look at mail merge https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java but what I generally recommend is content control data binding (OpenDoPE).  The content control data binding model is 1 input to 1 output though (so if you want n outputs in a single document, you'd have to concatenate them; that's the only reason I mention MailMerge, it can do that for you in simple cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Mail Merge as recommeded by Jason is the only **clean** solution in Java, my approach was POI/docx4j-less PLSQL.

Dirty but stupidly easy for not so complex .docx reports.

As I am using PLSQL on weblogic server, my approach was just directly for looping HTML + text from few tables into JSP, before setting content type to docx.

I will leave this here for record.